# Convert Object[]{ new Object[]{} } to int[][]

Tags: java, casting

I have code like this:

```
Object[] o1 = new Object[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Object[] o2 = new Object[]{ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
Object[] o3 = new Object[]{ 51, 42, 33, 24, 15 };

Object[] o4 = new Object[]{ o1, o2, o3 };
```

How I can convert `o4` to `int[][]`?

```
int[][] i1 = Arrays.copyOf(o4, o4.length, int[][].class);
int[][] i2 = (int[][]) o4;
```

Doesn't work :(

Comment: you have to convert each [] into int[] individually first.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should look like this :

```
Object[][] o4 = new Object[][]{{o1}, {o2}, {o3}};
```

And to cast it you have to use Integer instead like this :

```
Integer[][] i2 = (Integer[][]) o4;
```